# POST-Request in Xamarin WebView?

Tags: post, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I've a simple Xamarin.Forms page with a WebView in it, working well.
Now I want to call POST-Requests (sending form-data) for an URL.
Do I have to create 3 different views for Android, iOS and UWP to achieve that - or is there a way to implement the C# post-request code only once in the shared coded of my Xamarin-Forms project?

Comment: Try using `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 1):

As @hvaughan3 says you can use HttpClient, like so (from the shared code of your Xamarin Forms project):

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) };

HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToPost), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://your.url"), content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var responseFromServer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else {
    // handle errors
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how get I the response to a webview? My POST-Request is the post of form-data to login on a website. As a result, the user should be logged in and see the success page after login (and should work with the website as logged in user).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. The responseFromServer variable above will hold the html of the success page, you could use that for your webview, but I don't know how your website manages credentials for further requests, etc.

Comment: I've a webpage with a simple login form, that I want to bypass sending the credentials saved in my Xamarin-App via POST to the login-form-url and from there on the user should work with the webview logged in. Using the method with HttpClient, I only can pass the pure HTML to the webview with no cookie information.

Comment: I would suggest pointing the webview at the login form (or a customised version for your app) and letting the website handle it all. I'm assuming the webview will handle the cookies for you, but I haven't personally tried this kind of thing. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I think this it is at the end. Thanks for your effort :-)

Answer (score 1):

**POST Request Over Webview**
**For WkWebview**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PaymentWebview), typeof(PaymentWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MMFInvestorApp.iOS.Utils
{
    public class PaymentWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (NativeView != null)
            {
                var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new NSString(paymentwebview.url))); //Your Url
                request.HttpMethod = "POST";
                request.Body = NSData.FromString(paymentwebview.data); //Data for POST
                request["Content-Length"] = req.Body.Length.ToString();
                request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8";
                LoadRequest(request);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

**For UIWebview (Deprecated from April 2020**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PaymentWebview), typeof(PaymentWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MMFInvestorApp.iOS.Utils
{
    public class PaymentWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (NativeView != null)
            {
                var paymentwebview = Element as PaymentWebview;
                var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(new NSString(paymentwebview.url)));//Your Url
                request.Body = paymentwebview.data; //Data for POST
                request.HttpMethod = "POST";
                LoadRequest(request);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPcLient for form-URLencoded post request and then create a Custom Webview to handle cookies. Use the CookieWebView Nuget Package created by seansparkman.

Please check https://www.nuget.org/packages/CookieWebView/