# Implementing URL-encoded Form Data Submission in Xamarin.Forms WebView for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a POST request in a WebView in Xamarin.Forms for iOS. I've already implemented the WkWebViewRenderer and WebViewRenderer renderers as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61909231/15163133). This implementation works fine on Android, but on iOS, I'm encountering an issue.

I need to perform a form-data submission in the POST request. I've found a native method in Swift that converts data into URL-encoded format and returns a Data object. The Swift method is as follows:
https://github.com/asjservicios/pluspagosfirm/blob/master/PlusPagosFirm/Classes/FormularioModel.swift

```
 public func toUrlEncodedForm() -> Data? {
        var allowed = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
        allowed.insert(charactersIn: "-._~")
        
        if hash == nil {
            hash = SHA256Firm.getFirm(ipClient: ip, secretKey: secretKey, guidComercio: comercio, sucursalId: sucursalComercio, monto: monto)
        }
        
        var r = "";
        r += "Hash=\(hash!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
        r += "TransaccionComercioId=\(transaccionComercioId.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
        r += "COMERCIO=\(comercio.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
        
        var i = 0
        for p in producto {
            r += "Producto[\(i)]".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)! + "=\(p.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
            i += 1
        }
        
        r += "Monto=\(AESEncrypter.encryptString(plainText: monto, phrase: secretKey)!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
        r += "SucursalComercio=\(AESEncrypter.encryptString(plainText: sucursalComercio, phrase: secretKey)!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
        r += "CallbackCancel=\(AESEncrypter.encryptString(plainText: callbackCancel, phrase: secretKey)!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)&"
        r += "CallbackSuccess=\(AESEncrypter.encryptString(plainText: callbackSuccess, phrase: secretKey)!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)!)"
        
        return r.data(using: .utf8)
    }
```

This method works well in Swift, but I need to implement an equivalent solution in Xamarin.Forms for iOS. I've tried several approaches, but haven't been able to find a solution that works.

Could someone provide guidance on how I can implement a similar method in Xamarin.Forms for iOS that generates form data in URL-encoded format and returns it as an NSData object?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2523+url+encode+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Using C# URL encoding works on Android, but converting bytes to  on iOS results in server errors. Any suggestions for sending URL-encoded form data via Xamarin.Forms WebView on iOS?"NSData

Comment: I would expect identical results on both platforms.  Have you compared the results to see where exactly they differ?  And “server errors” is not a helpful description of the problem.  What is the specific error?